# iOS Play video black screen?

Tags: ios

I have been browsing through Google for various explanations but I STILL couldn't figure out when this code fires the screen is pitch black. Anyone able to spot a mistake?

**UPDATE**

```
- (IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender {
    NSURL *videoUrl = [[DataStore singletonInstance] getVideoUrl:self withUuid:self.eventDetailVC.event.uuid];
    if ([videoUrl checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:nil] == NO) {
        NSLog(@"Video doesn't not exist.");
        return;
    }
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoUrl];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                               object:player];
    [previewView addSubview:player.view];
    player.view.frame = previewView.bounds;
    player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    [player play];
}

- (void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"moviePlayBackDidFinish: called");
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                                  object:player];
    // Checking for errors
    NSDictionary *notiUserInfo = [notification userInfo];
    if (notiUserInfo != nil) {
        NSError *errorInfo = [notiUserInfo objectForKey:@"error"];
        if ([[errorInfo domain] isEqualToString:@"MediaPlayerErrorDomain"]) {
            UIAlertView *notice = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                                             message:[errorInfo localizedDescription] 
                                                            delegate:self 
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [notice show];
            return;
        }
    }
    // Remove from view
    [player.view removeFromSuperview];
    [player stop];
}
```

FYI moviePlayBackDidFinish is NOT called at all. I don't know why.

Comment: are you checking this in the simulator or the device?

Comment: Could you attach the video URL? It might have something to do with the content itself.

Comment: Like @stavash suggested, this may be a content issue. I've seen this occur when the video content is not in a format that the video player supports. I'd start by trying out other videos and seeing if you have success playing them so you can at least determine if it's just a content issue.

Comment: FYI the video is shot on the iphone so I don't know if that really is the problem.

Comment: Try registering for the `MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification` as well and log the `loadState` in the selector to narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: Pls suggest here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54745359/avplayer-shows-black-screen-when-playing-multiple-videos-in-swift3-ios

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create property for MPMoviePlayerController, because you retain view after adding it as subview, but not retain controller.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *player;

...

@synthesize player = _player;

...

- (IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *videoUrl = [[DataStore singletonInstance] getVideoUrl:self withUuid:self.eventDetailVC.event.uuid];
    if ([videoUrl checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:nil] == NO)
    {
        NSLog(@"Video doesn't not exist.");
        return;
    }
    self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoUrl];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                               object:nil];
    [previewView addSubview:_player.view];
    _player.view.frame = previewView.bounds;
    _player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    [_player play];
}

- (void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSLog(@"moviePlayBackDidFinish: called");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                                  object:nil];
    // Checking for errors
    NSDictionary *notiUserInfo = [notification userInfo];
    if (notiUserInfo != nil)
    {
        NSError *errorInfo = [notiUserInfo objectForKey:@"error"];
        if ([[errorInfo domain] isEqualToString:@"MediaPlayerErrorDomain"])
        {
            UIAlertView *notice = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                                             message:[errorInfo localizedDescription] 
                                                            delegate:self 
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [notice show];
            return;
        }
    }
    // Remove from view
    [_player.view removeFromSuperview];
    [_player stop];
    self.player = nil;
}
```

Comment: You are Gendalf White :D
Thank you!

Comment: Pls suggest here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54745359/avplayer-shows-black-screen-when-playing-multiple-videos-in-swift3-ios