# Objective-C iOS MPMoviePlayerController not play movie nothing return

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

Thats must play movie in TVOut if it exist if not thats must play movie in internal screen.
But it not play movie just shown blue screen as i set player background player.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

If i set tvout hardware in emulator then it show player blue screen on tvout and return message in console:

> 2013-12-17 23:57:59.576 RAT[8609:70b] Application windows are expected
>   to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

Code is:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  RAT
//
//  Created by Dmitriy Pushkarev on 28/11/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 ЯB RoyalBlue. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end



@implementation ViewController


MPMoviePlayerController *player;
UIWindow *newwindow;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



    player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8"]];




    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player play];
    [player.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];

    player.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    player.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    CGSize maxSize;




    if([[UIScreen screens]count] > 1) {
        NSLog(@"external screen");
        newwindow = [[UIWindow alloc] init];
        // There is a external display.
        UIScreenMode *maxScreenMode;
        for(int i = 0; i < [[[[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex:1] availableModes]count]; i++)
        {
            UIScreenMode *current = [[[[UIScreen screens]objectAtIndex:1]availableModes]objectAtIndex:i];
            if(current.size.width > maxSize.width)
            {
                maxSize = current.size;
                maxScreenMode = current;
            }
        }
        UIScreen *external = [[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex:1];
        external.currentMode = maxScreenMode;
        newwindow.screen = external;
        // setting external display size.
        CGPoint point = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
        // CGSize size = CGSizeMake(1024.0f, 768.0f);
        CGSize size = maxSize;
        CGRect frame = player.view.frame;
        frame.origin = point;
        frame.size.width = size.width;
        frame.size.height = size.height;
        [player.view setFrame:frame];
        [player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlModeHidden];
        [player prepareToPlay];
        [player play];
        [newwindow addSubview:player.view];
        [newwindow makeKeyAndVisible];

    } else {

        [self.view addSubview:player.view];
        [player.view becomeFirstResponder];

        NSLog(@"Display not connected");
    }


    ///////////////////////////////
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Progress...
Ok. I update code and now it's works on internal display only.
On TVout i see only blue screen and listen sound from video but nothing to view only blue.

And console message - Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

More progress..
All works fine! But i get message in log: Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062103/ios-play-video-black-screen/11129534

Answer (score 0):

I dot know if this is your only problem, but your player will be deallocated after viewDidLoad exits, because you create it as a local variable. Create a strong property for it, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Create your player as a property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerViewController *streamPlayer;
```

In viewDidLoad play the video:

```
NSURL *streamURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/nasatv/NTV-Public-IPS.m3u8"];
_streamPlayer = [[CSJMovieViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:streamURL];
[_streamPlayer.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:_streamPlayer.view];
[_streamPlayer.moviePlayer play];
```

I'm not certain why you're creating your own `UIWindow` object.  This should not be necessary to play back a video. You should be able to just add your player to the view of your `UIViewController`.  I suspect that the error message you are getting may be a result of creating that window.

The problem line is probably:

```
[newwindow addSubview:player.view];
```

From what I can see in your code there is no `UIViewController` set as a `rootViewController` on your `UIWindow` and there should be.

Comment: Thank you. But i have other trouble now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I solve problem i see movie on tv out but message in console still loging -  Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch.

What i need do?